# LifecycleListener is not listening after server start when the server type = periodic

Tags: tomcat8, tomcat9

I have created an `EventHookListener` which is implementing `LifecycleListener`. I have overridden  `lifecycleEvent()` method and keep listening to the server by printing server type and server state.

Code snippet:

```
@Override
public void lifecycleEvent(LifecycleEvent arg0) {
    Lifecycle lifecycle = arg0.getLifecycle();
    System.out.println("Lifecycle:"+lifecycle);
    if (lifecycle == null) {
      return;
    }
    String type = arg0.getType();
    System.out.println("Type:"+type);
    if (type == null) {
      return;
    }
    String stateName = lifecycle.getStateName();
    System.out.println("StateName:"+stateName);
    if (stateName == null) {
       return;
    }
}
```

For tomcat **version 9.0.26** the tomcat server keeps listening if the server is up. and below log is coming in `Catalina.out`:
But in **9.0.26 version** tomcat server keeps listening if the server is up.

23-Sep-2019 16:36:08.381 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Lifecycle:StandardServer[8005]
Type:after_start
StateName:STARTED

> current directory: /tmp
>   Exit code: 0
>
> 23-Sep-2019 16:36:08.407 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [8,239]
>   milliseconds Lifecycle:StandardServer[8005] Type:periodic
>   StateName:STARTED

But for any other version of tomcat (ex. 9.0.6 version or 8.5.45), the lifecycle listener is not listening once the tomcat server reaches to "after_start" state.

ex.

Lifecycle:StandardServer[8005]
Type:after_start
StateName:STARTED

> current directory: /tmp
>   Exit code: 0
>   23-Sep-2019 16:48:10.422 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 681 ms

Can anyone help with any clue which I am missing here?
This feature of the `Lifecycle listener` is only working in **9.0.26 version** but not in the older version. Though the LifecycleListener class contents are the same for older tomcat as well as the latest tomcat version.

Answer (score 0):

The scheduler that fires the periodic events was moved from the Service to the Server in 9.0.14 so in Tomcat versions prior to 9.0.14 you won't see periodic events for LifecycleListeners attached to the Server.

If you want consistent behaviour across Tomcat versions you could move your listener to the Service and then do `((Service) arg0).getServer()` to access the Server object.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Is there any dummy code implementation to access server object? Please give some code snippet for this implementation.

Comment: If I implement Service interface I need to implement all methods of Service and LifeCycle interface. How can i get rid of implementing unnecessary methods in the customized listener class?

Comment: Here is another implementation of listener class to access Server object.            
 
 public class HookService implements LifecycleListener {

    @Override
    public void lifecycleEvent(LifecycleEvent arg0) {

        Service lifecycle = (Service)arg0.getLifecycle();
        Server server = lifecycle.getServer();
      
        String type = arg0.getType();
        System.out.println("Type:"+type);
       
        String stateName = server.getStateName();
        System.out.println("StateName:"+stateName);
    }
}

Comment: In server.xml added below entry under Service tag.                 
<Service name="Catalina">
  <Listener className="com.oracle.event.listener.HookService"/>

Comment: But still periodic events for LifecycleListeners (attached to the Server) is not coming in catalina.out file.

11-Oct-2019 23:20:25.506 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Lifecycle:StandardService[Catalina]
Server:StandardServer[8005]
STARTING
Type:after_start
StateName:STARTING
11-Oct-2019 23:20:25.509 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [660] milliseconds

How can I get the periodic events in any tomcat version prior to 9.0.14? Any help would be appreciated.